# Paritions counts of tables across different datasets in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking a way to find the total no of partitions(count of partitions to find ahead if any table hitting 4000 limit threshold.) across bigquery tables  in all datasets of a project. COuld someone please help me with the query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS` metadata table in order to extract partitions information from a whole schema/dataset.

It works as follows:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  `project.schema.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
```

In case you want to look at a specific table, you just need to include it in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  `project.schema.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
WHERE 
  table_name = 'partitioned_table'
```

Comment: Curious to know is there a way to track when was the last time a table was accessed by  other tables. ?